# Using an SSRS Dataset as a source for SSIS

Tags: reporting-services, ssis

Is it possible to use an SSRS dataset query file as an SQL expression in SSIS for importing data?
I am looking to reduce report run-time and would like to prepare the dataset's data in advance without having to duplicate the query in SSIS. 
Thanks
DW

Comment: Your query would still fire 2X at the database right? Or are you planning on exec once, report twice? Either way, you'd probably need to stick the result set in a table if you want to reduce run-time.

Comment: Yes using a table is one option l have seen creating a temp table see this link - http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#temptables, or https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/  My suggestion would be to use a stored procedure, if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you really want to go from SSRS to SSIS or vice versa.

If the intent is to preprocess data in SSIS for rendering in a report (Think real-time EII)
then have a look at:
[Configuring Reporting Services to Use SSIS Package Data](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345250%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

if instead you want to go from SSRS Into SSIS. I would execute the report and store the output to the files system. then pick upo the resulting file from SSIS.  see this link for more info:
[File Share Delivery in Reporting Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159264.aspx)

Another potential option is to use the SSRS Web service api or directly pull a cached or snapshot report execution out of either the ReportServerTempDB or the ReportServerDB  respectively though this is probably overkill.

The approach smells a bit wrong almost as if you are using SSRS as the ETL tool.  I'd like to hear more about why you are going this route.

Comment: More details about why I'm considering a caching-type option: The report cover page contains the names of all of its subreports. A subreport may contain more than one title included in the cover page. If a particular section in a subreport (or entire subreport) is missing data (found through a complex sql query) then the same logic needs to be used to hide the name of the subreport in the cover page.

Comment: Looking at your latest comment. You know which sub-reports should be hidden or shown depending a complex bit of sql, which l guess takes time to run? If so could you run the a stored proc which populates a table with the two columns, one containing the sub-report name, the other bit value which indicates if the sub report has any data. Create a sql agent job that runs on a schedule which runs a stored proc updates the table with sub-report details?  Use the table for the front page the bit value then becomes visibility of that sub report